# C# Foreach checkbox checked in a panel

Tags: c#, checkbox, foreach, indexing, panel

I am trying to check each checkbox that is checked within my panel1. Then show the item checked in label1. I can not get it to work with a panel and checkboxes...below is what i have for code. Any suggestions would be great!
Thanks

```
foreach (int indexChecked in panel1)
{
            str1 += panel1.Items[indexChecked].ToString() + ", ";
            label1.Visible = true;
}
        label14.Text = str1;
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem, what error do you get ? what do you mean by "can't get it to work" does it compile, what is the output that you get ?

Comment: Also, Name your controls! panel1, label1, label2, label3. So hard to read once applications get bigger, constantly checking which one is which.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**solution 1:**

```
   String str1="";
   foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox) c).Checked)                      
        str1 += c.Text+ ", "; 
    }

    str1=str1.Trim();
    str1=str1.Substring(0,str1.Length-1);
    label14.Text = str1;
```

**Solution 2:**  if you want to add each checked `CheckBox` Item into `ListView`

Try This:

```
   listView1.Items.Clear();
   foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox) c).Checked)                      
          listView1.Items.Add(c.Text);
    }
```

Comment: This is perfect!! One last question, how can i show it in a list view. If multiple checboxes are checked, for them to start new row?

Comment: @hexc: so do you want to show each checkbox text in new row in listview?

Comment: Just show each checkbox in label or listview, but for each checkbox checked it puts in new line.

Comment: @hexc: check my edited answer with `solution 2`, please mark it as answer if it helps you.

Comment: @hexc: You are welcome :) , I'm glad tobe help of you.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly get if checkbox is checked:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
            {
                if (((CheckBox)c).Checked == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Controls.OfType does not exist in ASP.net

Comment: It is available in Asp.Net and my example code is based on ASP.Net